# make apt-get less verbose

Tags: debian, awk, apt

I´m on Debian 16.04 and built myself a shell script to simplify all the update stuff and I regularly call it with `sudo`:

```
apt-get -qy update
apt-get -qq upgrade
apt-get -qq dist-upgrade
apt-get -qq autoremove
apt-get -qq autoclean
```

Works fine; but it´s far too verbose for my taste; all I want are lists of errors of any kind and of updated packages (including the disk space required by the update, if possible).
So I´d like to either make the output of `apt-get` less verbose or filter the (german) output of the script.

As I couldn find no way to tune `apt-get` output to my desires, I guess it´s going to be an output filter. But I´m totally overwhelmed by `awk` and consorts.

side note:
I´d be happy with english output. Am I correct in the assumption that adding `export LC_ALL=C` to the beginning of the script will accomplish that?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I guess I fixed it.

Comment: Try it `LC_ALL=C script`. I think using `LANG=C` is more common. You could get some words in the output lines that you want to see and then filter with awk or sed `awk '/word1|word2/ {print}'` or `sed -nr '/word1|word2/ p'`